# data in serializer is always empty

Tags: python, django

I have following serializer:

```
class AdminSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        user = data.get("user_pk")
        total_licenses = data.get("total_licenses")
        #here i do some validation with the vars
```

But my data is always empty. This is part of my view

```
serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
serializer = serializer_class(
    data=self.request.data,
)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

This is my unit test request:

```
response = self.client.patch(
    url,
    data={"user_pk": self.user.pk, "total_licenses": 3},
)
```

Why is my 'data' always empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify fields in your serializer:

```py
class AdminSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  user_pk = serializers.IntegerField()
  total_licenses = serializers.IntegerField()


  def validate(self, data):
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `serializer.save()` before you can access `.data` attribute on a serializer. Otherwise, you can access `.validated_data` attribute on your serializer

Comment: You mean adding serializer.save() after is_valid() is my view? That doesn't work

Comment: Do you return data from your `validate` function?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, but the data in my serializer is always empty.

Comment: Yes I do, but the problem is my data in my validate function is empty. Example to get user = data.get("user_pk")